# How can I get objects from ram(cache) and checksum them?

Tags: ruby, object, checksum, ram

I want to get objects from ram on current machine which my code is running on. How can I get them and checksum after getting? I'm coding ruby and I want to get all objects on ram at runtime, and could it be done continuously?